# Why is my jQuery having an error when I put this line in?

Tags: javascript, jquery-validate

Why is my jQuery having an error when I put this line in?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $(".arrowbutton").click(function(){
                id = $(this).attr('rel');
                $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"/upvote",
                data:{'id':id},
                beforeSend:function() {
                },
                success:function(html){
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                });
                return false;
                });

            });
    </script>
```

When I remove `$(this).hide();` it's fine. But, I want it to hide!!!

Comment: *Please please* **always** post the actual error message. Why is that *so* difficult?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` doesn't refer to you arrow button, but it refers to the AJAX Request object.

```
$(".arrowbutton").click(function(){
  var that = this;
  var id = $(this).attr('rel');
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"/upvote",
    data:{'id':id},
    beforeSend:function() {

    },
    success:function(html){
      $(that).hide();
    }
  });

  return false;
});
```

jQuery calls your `success` function more or less like this:

```
handleSuccess: function( s, xhr, status, data ) {
  // If a local callback was specified, fire it and pass it the data
  if ( s.success ) {
    s.success.call( s.context, data, status, xhr );
  }

  // Fire the global callback
  if ( s.global ) {
    jQuery.triggerGlobal( s, "ajaxSuccess", [xhr, s] );
  }
},
```

The first argument of the call method sets the `this` keyword in the success function to `s.context`

Answer (score 1):

Because `$(this)` doesn't return what you think it does in the success callback. You could use a closure:

```
$(function(){
    $('.arrowbutton').click(function(){
        var button = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/upvote',
            data: { id: this.rel },
            beforeSend:function() {
            },
            success:function(html) {
                button.hide();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$(this)` is referring to the Ajax request, not the surrounding button.

Try using a closure like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $(".arrowbutton").click(function(){
            var arrowbutton = $(this);
            id = $(this).attr('rel');
            $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/upvote",
            data:{'id':id},
            beforeSend:function() {
            },
            success:function(html){
                arrowbutton.hide();
            }
            });
            return false;
            });

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

"this" does mean this in all situations, because you are inside a new function that is the new this.

Check this tutorial out to learn all the different ways you can deal with it:

- http://justin.harmonize.fm/index.php/2009/09/an-introduction-to-javascripts-this/

Comment: Not *strictly* true. Just because you're in a new function, it does not mean `this` will have a new context: If the new function was a method on the DOM element, then `this` would still be the same `this` (provided no `call` or `apply` was used 8-) ).